# Keras model load_weights fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have a rather weird problem. When I save my model with

```
model = load_model(name)
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/home/drbunsen/Downloads/code/neural/imageClassification.py", line 52, in <module>
model = ms.loadModel("fashion")
File "/home/drbunsen/Downloads/code/neural/modelSaver.py", line 22, in loadModel
model = load_model(name)
File "/home/drbunsen/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 492, in load_wrapper
return load_function(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/drbunsen/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 584, in load_model
model = _deserialize_model(h5dict, custom_objects, compile)
File "/home/drbunsen/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 273, in _deserialize_model
model_config = json.loads(model_config.decode('utf-8'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

I am just following examples I found here and on the internet. Can anyone shed some light on this? Thanks in advance.

Debian stable
Keras 2.3.0
Python 3.7.3
Tensor2.0.0-beta1

Comment: What is the version of h5py? `import h5py; print(h5py.__version__)`. And consider to upgrade keras and tensorflow.

Comment: @Kaveh my pip3 only goes to those version :'( Maybe a Debian thing. But the h5py worked. Thanks.

Comment: This issue has been asked many many times here, please search in the site before asking, as the answer might be already here.

Comment: I searched and read the first 7 results, which had all to do with other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip/pip3 install h5py==2.10.0` should solve the problem; also as @Kaveh mentioned consider upgrading to a bigger version of TF+Keras.

Comment: My pip3 only goes to those version :'( Maybe a Debian thing. But the h5py worked. Thanks.